# Error whilst trying to build Jenkins Performance Plugin in IntelliJ

Tags: python, jenkins, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am trying to build Jenkins Performance plug-in locally on my macbook using IntelliJ and it throws error running tests whilst trying to run mvn package.

[image]

Comment: Update your python version to 3

Comment: Thanks a lot, @BigBounty. I was just waiting for someone's push. I will give it a go. Could you please answer my question so if the solution works I can then mark that as an answer. Thanks. Cheers !!!